# Keep Font Results as Image?

Tags: vba, fonts, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have an excel file that uses a unique font type to convert a raw value such as {ABCDEF|123456} to a bar code image.

[image: Example]

I need to send the file to a machine that does not have adequate permissions to install this custom font.

Is there a way to keep this font type as an image within Excel? Or to keep the font output without the font installed on the current machine?

While I have found that using Copy as Picture => Appearance: "As Shown on Screen" works manually, I can't seem to get the VBA code to work well with this as I have to do this thousands of time in a single file.

Comment: Are you intent just to store rendered barcodes as images, or to keep full functionality on a machine that has no font installed? Please add to the question some samples of value and screenshots of corresponding barcode output.

Comment: copyaspicture may work for you? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836633.aspx

Comment: @omegastripes - I've added an example.  The ultimate goal is to print the font output in a PDF on a machine that does not have the font.

Comment: @Nathan_sav - This is essentially what I'm doing manually, but I can't get the VBA to actually paste as an image. When I uninstall the font on my machine, these are reverted to the raw value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to copy and paste a bitmap over a cell, not a vector:

```vb
Range("F1").Select
Selection.CopyPicture Format:=xlBitmap
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Bitmap"
```

Comment: @HazyKingdom have you tried the code? Does it solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Thank you very much for this solution.